# greenfoot making wall for ping pong game

Tags: java, if-statement

Hi iam making a ping pong game in greenfoot. But i dont know why the top wall dont bounce the ball. I think the that the if-statement give the problem. Can someone help me:) this is my code:

```
public class ball extends Actor
{
    int startX = 3;
    int startY = 3;


    public void act()
    {
        // Add your action code here.
        move();
        wall();
        playerBounce();
        computer();
    }
    public void move(){
        setLocation(getX()+ startX ,getY()+startY);
    }
    public void wall(){
        if(getY()> getWorld().getHeight() - getImage().getHeight()/2){
        startY = startY * -1;
    }
if(getY() <= 50) {
            startY = startY * +1;
    }
    }

    public void playerBounce(){

    Actor playt = getOneIntersectingObject(player2.class);
    if (playt != null){
        startX = startX *-1;

    }
    }
    public void computer(){
    Actor playo = getOneIntersectingObject(player1.class);
    if (playo != null){
        startX = startX *-1;

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: How does x and y correlate with the walls? is max x the top, or is max y?

Comment: Y = 0 thats the top wall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably has something to do with the height being derived from getHeight() because it it doesn't bounce, then Y * -1 would probably be equal to 0 * -1, which would mean nothing.

Comment: if(getY() <=50) this dont work:( if(getY()> getWorld().getHeight() - getImage().getHeight()/2){ this is working. howe can i solve it?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand your question. Could you rephrase that?

Comment: Thanx for help:) but it was the compiler that didnt work. Iam using greenfoot and I now know that greenfoot doesnt work always as wanted.